# EEVEE. Reflection of gloss surface in another gloss surface is causing weird bars of light instead of smooth lighting

Tags: eevee-render-engine, lighting, reflection

As you can see in the render the "Stairs" on the left are being reflected in the shapes on the right but the light from the stairs looks like caution tape or something.  Is there any way to smooth that out so the lighting isn't broken up into those bars?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, could you add a little more info about your lighting setup and the materials you used ?

Comment: I've added screenshots of the Gloss shader used for the platform and the Emission shader used for the sun.